# ActionListener in java performs action on the second click

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I am programming my first complex application in Java, Swing. When I have added ActionListener to my JButton.

```
ActionListener changeButton = new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(startButton.getText() == "Spustit") {
            startButton.setText("STOP");
        } else {
            startButton.setText("Spustit");
        }
    }
}
```

I am adding ActionListener to the button itself

```
private void startButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    startButton.addActionListener(changeButton);
}
```

Can you tell me where I coded ActionListener badly?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Have you debugged whether the method gets called?

Comment: @Smutje: Well, method is called, but not on the first click. It "works" only on second or third click

Comment: Where you have coded it badly? For example here: `startButton.getText() == "Spustit"`. Compare Strings with `equals` and not with `==`. Although, due to the use of intented String, your comparison might work, but you should fix it.

Comment: If you don't want this behavior (actionlistener works after pressing the second time), why you're adding it after the button was pressed the first time? Doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @Tom thank you, I have already changed it to equals method, but I have still the problem that the action is performed on the second click to the button.
    
edit: ActionListener is added with the first click?

Comment: Yes and it is easy to understand why this happens. Because you're adding the listener `changeButton` in the event method `startButtonActionPerformed`. So the user has to press the button at least once to "install" the `changeButton` listener.

Comment: Thanks Tom, it is really working now. Great help here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have coded the ActionListener good enough to be working, at least, for the action listener itself. The problem is that you are adding the action listener after an event (your second sample), thus your action listener will get called the second time you will click it.

A solution is very simple:

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      //...
    }
 });
```

Now the action listener should activate on the first click if you directly add a new ActionListener to the button, not after an action is performed

Answer (score 1):

Why are you adding the actionlistener in actionPerformed? I think you should do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JButton startButton = new JButton("Spustit");
    ActionListener changeButton = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (startButton.getText() == "Spustit") {
                startButton.setText("STOP");
            } else {
                startButton.setText("Spustit");
            }
        }
    };
    startButton.addActionListener(changeButton);
    // Add it to your panel where you want int
}
```